# what is the difference between foo["keyname"] and foo.keyname in js?

Tags: javascript

If you have an object, for example:

```js
const myObject = {
    "MyValue":5
}
```

or

```js
const myObject = {
    MyValue:5
}
```

would there be a difference between using `myObject["MyValue"]` and `myObject.MyValue`?

Also, would the `""` around the keys in the object make a difference as well? Are they both just preferences?

Comment: no there is no difference. `myObject["MyValue"]` is usually used if you have an variable and want to access some value from the object like `myObject[myVariable]` because this wont work `myObject.myVariable`

Comment: @bill.gates no difference *in this code*. There are differences in other cases.

Comment: Sometimes object keys have special characters which mean other things in javascript.  So myObject["test-value"] would be fine, whereas myObject.test-value would be an error (it would try to evaluate myObject.test minus value).